# Warum sagt man "fernsehen" (deutsches Wort), aber "telefonieren" (Fremdwort)?

Tags: etymology

Ich habe mich gefragt, warum man im Deutschen

> fernsehen

sagt, also ein deutsches Wort verwendet, während man für

> telefonieren

ein Fremdwort verwendet.

Die entsprechenden Substantive sind ähnlich gelagert. Es gibt zwar "Fernsprecher" als Synonym für "Telefon", das ist aber eher ungebräuchlich bzw. veraltet. Im Gegensatz dazu ist "Fernsehgerät" oder "Fernseher" viel üblicher als "TV-Gerät".

Comment: Beantwortest du die Frage nicht schon selbst? Es sind eben die gebräuchlichen Begriffe...

Comment: Praktikabiliät, Einfachheit, Bequemlichkeit als Faktoren? "Wollen wir heute abend was televisionieren?" Zu umständlich... also "fernsehen". Dagegen ist "Telefon" vielleicht auf Dauer einfacher auszusprechen als "Fernsprecher"? Nur eine Hypothese...

Comment: Ich habe die Frage als "primarly opinion based" geflagged, da ich nicht glaube, dass es eine andere Antwort als "das sind eben die Begriffe die sich durchgesetzt haben" geben kann.

Comment: Da könnte man auch gleich fragen, warum das "-vision" aus "Television" aus dem Lateinischen entliehen ist, das "-phon(e)" aus "Telephon(e)" dagegen aus dem Altgriechischen. So etwas passiert dauernd.

Comment: @raznagul: Angenommen, *»das sind eben die Begriffe die sich durchgesetzt haben«* wäre die richtige Antwort: Inwiefern ist das *»primarly opinion based«*? Wenn diese Antwort zutrifft, lässt sie sich ja prima mit Fakten belegen, ganz unabhängig von den persönlichen Vorlieben jener, die diese Antwort geben.

Comment: @Annatar: Ich stimme dir vollkommen zu! Bitte sehr, stelle diese Frage: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: @HubertSchölnast  Ich hatte ähnliche Gedanken. Entweder es gibt Kausalitäten und Wirkkräfte - dann kann man sie (wenn man sie kennt) hier darlegen oder jedenfalls Hypothesen über sie anstellen. Oder aber es ist ein chaotischer Prozess (wie in der Quantenphysik), bei dem Dinge geschehen, die nicht kausal sind und die "halt passieren", aber dann kann man auch dies als Hypothese darlegen und die daneben oder im Anschluss wirkenden Kräfte betrachten. Drittens kann man natürlich immer Sprachformung auch als Geschichte betrachten und erzählen, "wie es dazu kam" (und nicht anders).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das hat damit zu tun, wie die Begriffe bei der Einführung der Geräte in die deutsche Sprache eingeführt wurden.

### Telefon

alte Schreibweise: **Telephon**

Das Telefon hat bekanntermaßen viele Erfinder, darunter war auch der Deutsche Johann Philipp Reis, und auch wenn er sich den Ruhm für die Erfindung des Geräts z.B. mit Alexander Graham Bell (und anderen) teilen muss, so ist er doch der alleiniger Erfinder des Wortes *»Telephon«*.

Andere Forscher und Ingenieure übernahmen dieses griechische Wort, was vor allem dadurch erleichtert wurde, dass es in allen Sprachen ein Fremdwort war, das aus einer Wissenschaftssprache stammt.

Der Begriff »Fernsprechapparat« wurde erst später in Umlauf gebracht, und klang immer schon holpriger als das elegantere Wort »Telephon«, weshalb beim *Fernsprecher* immer Uniform und Beamtentum, vielleicht sogar auch Militär mitschwingt.

Diese amtlichen Konnotationen hatte das Wort *»Telephon«* nie, daher war es beliebter und setzte sich viel stärker durch.

---

### Fernsehen

Ich finde die Quelle leider nicht mehr, bin mir aber recht sicher, dass Karl Ferdinand Braun, der Erfinder der Braunschen Röhre, den Begriff »Fernsehen« (als deutsches Wort) eingeführt hat. Soweit ich weiß, wurde der Begriff »Television« von deutschen Ingenieuren eher selten benutzt.

Ein Verb *televisionieren* hat sich im deutschen Sprachraum nie entwickelt. Das Verb *fernsehen* war aber von Anfang an etabliert.

Überhaupt drang der Begriff *Television* oder die Abkürzung *TV* erst seht spät in den deutschen Sprachraum ein. So hießen z.B. in meiner Kindheit und Jungend die beiden Kanäle des ORF *»FS1«* und *»FS2«*, wobei *»FS«* ganz simpel für *»Fernsehen«* stand. Man hätte die beiden Kanäle ja auch *»TV1«* und *»TV2«* nennen können, tat das aber nicht, weil der Begriff *TV* meiner Wahrnehmung nach erst in den 1980er-Jahren im deutschen Wortschatz auftauchte, und das auch nur als Modewort.

Bis heute ist es dem Nomen *Televison* nicht gelungen, das Nomen »Fernsehen« zu verdrängen, und für das Verb *fernsehen* ist nicht einmal ein Kandidat in Sichtweite, der es verdrängen könnte.

Comment: Als anderes Wort für *fernsehen* wäre noch *televidieren* möglich (wg. Lat. *videre*). Es klänge aber doch recht angestrengt. Gut eingebürgert ist ja auch (im Mündlichen) *Fernseh kucken* bzw. *fernsehkucken*, oder auch *fernkucken*.

Comment: Also, dass *Fernseher* von **Karl Ferdinand Braun** eingeführt oder benutzt wurde, ist vermutlich eine Legende und ich glaube Dir das nicht ohne seriöse Referenz. Braun starb nämlich 1918, noch vor der ersten Bildprojektion in einer Kathodenstrahlröhre.

Answer (score 2):

Deutsche Wörter und Bezeichnungen für Produkte oder Alltagsgegenstände können eine sehr vielfältige Herkunft haben. Selbst wenn sie scheinbar ähnliche Bereiche abdecken, so hängt es sehr stark davon ab, wann sie eingeführt wurden, wo sie hergestellt wurden, wer sie hergestellt hat. Oft reichen einfache Dinge oder ein kleiner Skandal im Zusammenhang mit der Einführung, um sich in der Alltagsverwendung durch zu setzen. Woher nun die beiden Wörter kommen müsste man genau recherchieren. Es gibt m.E. keinen  speziellen Grund, warum mal ein Anglizismus oder ein anderes Fremdwort verwendet wird. Eine "offizielle" Stelle zur Anerkennung einer Bezeichnung gibt es nicht.

Answer (score 1):

Schon zu Beginn der Telefonie war der Begriff *telephonieren* (später *telefonieren*) gebräuchlich, da die Telefonie ja die *Telegraphie*, bzw. das *Telegraphieren* abgelöst hatte.

[image]
<sup>https://books.google.com/ngrams</sup>

Das Fernsehen hatte nie diese Funktion einer direkte Nachrichtenübermittlung über weite Strecken, so dass hier ein Analogiebildung mit *Tele-* weit weniger in Frage kam (anders *Telefax* und *Videotelefonie*).

Dennoch musste man kein neues Wort erfinden, denn das Fernsehen gab es bereits in der Optik/Augenheilkunde und der (Para-)Psychologie.

> Das Fernsehen als Funktion des transcendentalen Subjekts. <sup>[Sphinx 15, 1893](https://books.google.de/books/download/Sphinx.enw?id=wokXAAAAYAAJ&output=enw)</sup>
>
> Daraus folgt, dass der schon beim Fernsehen nach innen vom Hornhautcentrum abweichende Pupillenmittelpunkt beim Nahesehen noch weiter nach innen abweicht <sup>[Verhandlungen des Naturhistorisch-medizinischen Vereins zu Heidelberg, Volume 2, 1862](https://books.google.de/books?id=ZpsDAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22Fernsehen%22&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=%22Fernsehen%22&f=false)</sup>

Spannend ist, dass man umgangssprachlich häufig gar nicht so sehr vom *Fernsehen* spricht, sondern das Gerät in den Vordergund stellt:

> Die Kinder wollen immer nur Fernsehn schauen.
>   Wollen wir heute Fernsehn gucken?
>   Schon beim Frühstück Fernsehn glotzen finde ich Käse.
>   Wir sind gestern wieder vorm Fernseher eingeschlafen.

Comment: "Das Fernsehen hatte nie diese Funktion einer direkte Nachrichtenübermittlung über weite Strecken, so dass hier ein Analogiebildung mit Tele- weit weniger in Frage kam" - und dafür suchte man sich dann ein Wort mit dem Präfix *fern-* aus, ja?